# Символьная строка Си

Tags: c

Уже 3 дня никак не могу разобраться и дописать программу:

С клавиатуры ввести предложение. Сформировать новое предложение из тех слов заданного, в которых нет указанной буквы (маленькой или большой). Напечатать новое предложение большими буквами и указать, сколько слов не попало в итоговый результат, или вывести сообщение об отсутствии искомых слов.

Прикол в том что мне нужно реализовать это не использую библиотечных функций, то есть, по сути, без <string.h>

Вот код что имею на данный момент:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(){
char s[MAX_SIZE];
char c;

printf("Enter string: ");
gets_s(s);

printf("Enter letter: ");
scanf_s("%c", &c);

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(s); i++) {
     if(s[i]==c) {
      ???
     }
}

return 0;
}
```

Заранее спасибо всем кто откликнется!!!

Comment: `sizeof(s)` это уже не правильно, почти наверняка вы прочли более короткую строку. Вместо этого проверяйте, что оредной `s[i]` не равен 0. (символьные строки завершаются нулем). Затем, вы должны определиться, какие символы входят в *слово* (остальные будут разделителями). Идея в том, что вы пропускаете разделители и запоминаете *начало слова* (индекс). После этого идете до разделителя. В этот момент вы зафиксировали слово. Если в ходе поиска смотреть, есть ли в слове искомая буква, то можно его посимвольно печатать, переводя все символы в верхний регистр. Далее повторяете это в цикле

Comment: так у вас есть ограничение с запретом использовать второй массив или нет?

Comment: Ограничений во 2 массиве нету